# (went to / have been to / had been to) + last year

Tags: tense

1. I went to Mexico last year.
2. I have been to Mexico in the last year.
3. I’d been to China last year.

The above sentences are taken from [www.quora.com](https://www.quora.com/What-is-wrong-with-this-sentence-Ive-been-to-China-last-year) and [www.englishpage.com](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html). It seems that they are well-formed but do 2 and 3 sound natural to native speakers?

Comment: Yes, but for number two, I would probably say something like, "I've been to Mexico **twice** in the last year [or so]." And I would say number three is wrong. I would not have used "last year" with the past perfect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Present Perfect but with specifying the time in the past](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/present-perfect-but-with-specifying-the-time-in-the-past)

Answer (score 1):

> I went to Mexico last year.

There's no problem with this one -- it' a simple statement!

> I have been to Mexico in the last year.

This one is fine, but is asking to be extended in some way, with something possibly in the present or the future. For example,

I have been to Mexico in the last year, *but don't think it's too soon to return.*  or
I have been to Mexico in the last year, *so I am familiar with the current political situation.*

> I’d been to China last year.

This one needs some extension, but with something also in the past. For example,

I’d been to China last year, *but I was happy to return earlier this year.* or
I’d been to China last year, *so I knew what to expect when I returned recently.*